# Excluding GNU as (GAS) standard startup code

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, gnu-assembler, gnu-arm

I want the GCC to exclude the startup code it link automatically with building process

what should i do?

So that i have my Own Startup assembly code defining labels (_start, _exit,..etc)

Comment: How are you linking your code?

Comment: i am using the GNU linker [ld]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC provides the `-nostartfiles`, `-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostdlib` options. [See documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Alternatively, you can call linker (`ld`) directly: it doesn't add anything by default, all objects (including the linker script) has to be specified manually. For an example of the `ld` invocation, run `gcc` with `-v` option: it would print full command lines of all other tools (including linker) it invokes.